# glVertex2d_Exec crashing on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, cocoa, opengl

I'm experiencing crashes in my app on Mac OS X (fully updated Mavericks). It is extremely hard to simulate, seems more or less random. But it crashes inside OpenGL. I googled it, and it seems I'm not the only one, but apparently nobody knows what it is. Any ideas?

```
Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x9b6b2952 __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x93681167 pthread_kill + 101
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9a5e6368 __abort + 187
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9a5e62ad abort + 172
4   com.apple.logic.pro             0x003e6729 std::ostream& TraceOutContainer<CEvs>(std::ostream&, CEvs, char const*, int) + 3842985
5   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x9708edeb _sigtramp + 43
6   ???                             0x257c648b 0 + 628909195
7   GLEngine                        0x92505243 glVertex2d_Exec + 96
8   libGL.dylib                     0x9b493201 glVertex2d + 46
9   com.company.MyApp       0x1fe75c26 MDrawerOpenGL::FillRectangleGradient(MRectT<int>, MColor, MColor, MOrientation::Enum, int) + 554
10  com.company.MyApp       0x2002ffec MDrawer::FillRectangleGradient(MRectT<int>, MColor, MColor, MOrientation::Enum, int) + 130
11  com.company.MyApp       0x1fed297d MBarMeter::PaintLines(MDrawer&, double, double, MColor) + 2437
12  com.company.MyApp   0x1fed30fa MBarMeter::Paint(MDrawer&) + 142
13  com.company.MyApp       0x1fe80305 MRenderer_ToWindow::PaintControl(MControl&, MRectT<int> const&) + 227
14  com.company.MyApp       0x1fe3ec35 MControl::PaintDispatch() + 303
15  com.company.MyApp       0x1fe3ec61 MControl::PaintDispatch() + 347
16  com.company.MyApp       0x1fe3ec61 MControl::PaintDispatch() + 347
17  com.company.MyApp       0x1fe3ec61 MControl::PaintDispatch() + 347
18  com.company.MyApp       0x1fe3ec61 MControl::PaintDispatch() + 347
19  com.company.MyApp       0x1fe3ec61 MControl::PaintDispatch() + 347
20  com.company.MyApp       0x1fe3eca8 MControl::PerformPaintDispatch() + 54
21  com.company.MyApp       0x1fdbde1a MWindowSystemCocoa::PaintWindow(MControl&, MRectT<int>, CGContext*) + 612
22  com.company.MyApp       0x1fdc272a -[MView drawRect:] + 236
23  com.apple.AppKit                0x987b8381 -[NSView _drawRect:clip:] + 4033
24  com.apple.AppKit                0x987b574a -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 2482
25  com.apple.AppKit                0x987b60c6 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 4910
26  com.apple.AppKit                0x987b60c6 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 4910
27  com.apple.AppKit                0x987b60c6 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 4910
28  com.apple.AppKit                0x987b60c6 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 4910
29  com.apple.AppKit                0x987b60c6 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 4910
30  com.apple.AppKit                0x987b60c6 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 4910
31  com.apple.AppKit                0x987b4900 -[NSThemeFrame _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 290
32  com.apple.prokit                0x00ff01b7 -[NSProWindowFrame _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 95
33  com.apple.AppKit                0x987b1c67 -[NSView _displayRectIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:] + 3645
34  com.apple.AppKit                0x9878f75c -[NSView displayIfNeeded] + 1414
35  com.apple.AppKit                0x987ad77c -[NSWindow displayIfNeeded] + 324
36  com.apple.AppKit                0x987f7345 _handleWindowNeedsDisplayOrLayoutOrUpdateConstraints + 1107
37  com.apple.AppKit                0x98e6717b __83-[NSWindow _postWindowNeedsDisplayOrLayoutOrUpdateConstraintsUnlessPostingDisabled]_block_invoke1381 + 58
38  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x933e890d _runLoopObserverWithBlockContext + 29
39  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x933e835e __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 30
40  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x933e82af __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 399
41  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x933d915e __CFRunLoopRun + 974
42  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x933d8b1a CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 394
43  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x933d897b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
44  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x9b09fb7d RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 259
45  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x9b09f902 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 526
46  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x9b09f6dd _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 92
47  com.apple.AppKit                0x98651389 _DPSNextEvent + 1602
48  com.apple.AppKit                0x986508b0 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 119
49  com.apple.AppKit                0x9864319c -[NSApplication run] + 727
50  com.apple.prokit                0x00fc880d NSProApplicationMain + 353
51  com.apple.logic.pro             0x0002bad5 DummyConnection::DummyConnection() + 193
```

Comment: Just for clarification: Is your code calling `glVertex2d`? Since the previous entry in the call stack is from com.company.MyApp, I figure it's a direct call from your app, and not from some intermediate framework? Can you show us the code for the call? If it's indeed just `glVertex2d`, it's hard to imagine that you're causing the problem, since the call takes scalar values as arguments.

Comment: The number of times `PaintDispatch (...)` is called and the fact that it cannot figure out a function name for the address it returns to, makes me wonder if you're not blowing up your stack with recursion.

Comment: Yes, I'm calling glVertex2d myself. PaintDispatch is also recursive. So everything up to the point calling glVertex2d is fine.

Comment: I'm now thinking - I'm currently also solving a problem with memory copy - something goes wrong in an exreme almost-impossible-to-simulate-situation and calls memmove with a huge "count", so that it starts filling the memory up to a point it causes access violation. It is almost to debug, because it does that only in release mode and the stack seems completely destroyed. But could it somehow mess up the GL library? It's weird because in this case the stack is ok and as you pointed out glVertex2d just takes scalars.